# mvc 4: save date only without time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to ask if how to get date only without time. I tried in searching but different on the approach that I want. Here's my table

```
CREATE TABLE myRequest (
    [request_id]      INT        IDENTITY(1, 1)     NOT NULL,
    [date_requested]  DATETIME   DEFAULT(getdate()) NOT NULL
)
```

And here's my code

```
public void save()
{
   myRequest req = new myRequest
   {
        request_id = db.myRequest.Count() + 1,
        date_requested = DateTime.Now.Date
   };

    db.myRequest.Add(req);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Change your SQL data type to `DATE`

Comment: Thanks you for your help, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the column type of `date_requested` in your table to `DATE`.

Consider this table

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(
  DateOnlyColumn DATE     DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
  DateTimeColumn DATETIME DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL)
```

If you insert a row like this

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable] VALUES (GETDATE(), GETDATE())
```

Then you will see although both `DateOnlyColumn` and `DateTimeColumn` were feed with the same value but, `DateOnlyColumn` has just the date and `DateTimeColumn` has both the date and time portion. So passing the `DateTime.Now.Date` in C# code does not have any effect and SQL automatically will add a zero time to `DATETIME` columns. So if you don't want time values be stored in database just use `DATE` type for columns.